# why do I get error while running php mail function from cmd

Tags: php, cmd

I'm trying to use the php mail function from cmd,with following command:

```
php -r "\$from = \$to = 'your.emailaddress@gmail.com'; \$x = mail(\$to, 'subject'.time(), 'Hello World', 'From: '. \$from); var_dump(\$x);"
```

I get this error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "", expecting end of file in Command line code on line 1**
could it be because of wrong directory ? or what am I missing in the code ?

Comment: It would be easier if you inverted the quotes, and used single quotes to wrap PHP code. This way you wouldn't have to escape variable sigils.

Comment: @weirdan I tried and it didn;t work but I;m not sure if I did it correctly,because I didn;t uderstand well what you ment. is this right ? '(php -r '$from ="hello" $to = "your.emailaddress@gmail.com"; $x = mail($to, "subject".time(), "Hello World", "From: ". $from); var_dump($x);')'

Comment: Pasted that line into my ubuntu terminal. Works. Tested with bash and fish. Did you do that from windows command prompt?

Comment: yes I'm using windows

Comment: Then it looks like the windows terminal is handling the quotes different than *nix. Why don't you put that code into a php file and then run it via `php -f mycode.php`?

Comment: Windows CMD doesn't use backslashes for escapes, nor does it use dollar-signs (used by PHP) for interpolated variables.

Comment: Also, most ISPs block e-mail coming from SMTP clients or MTAs from residential IP blocks - so even if you have your `php.ini` correctly configured your e-mail still likely won't get through.

Answer (score 2):

The `\` character doesn't play any role in CMD—just get rid of it. Neither does `$`, so it doesn't need to be escaped:

```
C:\>php -r "$from = $to = 'your.emailaddress@example.com'; $x = mail($to, 'subject'.time(), 'Hello World', 'From: '. $from); var_dump($x);"
PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in Command line code on line 1

Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in Command line code on line 1
bool(false)
```

Whether it's a good idea is left as exercise for readers ;-)